# Rails web application error on start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to linux and rails and am trying to get a development server up and running. I have installed ruby/rails and had it working under localhost:3000. I can create a rails app and have it run.

I then installed apache 2/passenger. When I try to hit the IP address of the machine I am getting the following error:

```
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:

bundle install

If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

Is this app supposed to be run as the a-cjstewar user?
Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.

-------- The exception is as follows: -------

Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in `specs_for'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Here is my app1.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 122.112.8.102
    ServerAdmin user@email.com
    DocumentRoot /home/username/app1/public
    RailsEnv development
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
     <Directory "/home/username/app1/public">
       Require all granted
       Options FollowSymLinks
       # This relaxes Apache security settings.
       AllowOverride None
       # MultiViews must be turned off.
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

ruby -v

```
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
```

rails -v

```
Rails 5.1.2
```

apache2 -v

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
```

passenger -v

```
Phusion Passenger 5.1.6
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` in the project?

Comment: Yes I have. Everything is installed without any issues.

Comment: I mean, it's not without issue, is it! Was the `bundle install` run by the same user that is running the server, "a-cjstewar"?

Comment: Oh no, wait, passenger is trying to run the app on a different ruby, see the `2.3.0` in the file paths in the error, though you said you're running it on 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are running your application with a different Ruby than you think you are.

In order to get the Ruby 2.4.0p0 that you say your app should be running on, you should find out where that Ruby is located with

```
which ruby
```

Then, you can set that executable as the Ruby you want to use by using the `PassengerRuby` directive in your `<VirtualHost>`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    PassengerRuby: /path/to/ruby
    # other stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

Check out [the documentation for the PassengerRuby directive](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerruby) to learn more.

Comment: Yay! That was it. Once I added the path it is working now. I appreciate the help.